# killing python application after exiting it

Tags: python, exit, kill-process

I’m starting finishing off my new simple app and because Python isn’t my main programming language I’m struggling a lot. I would like to add a function which would kill everything - every service in the app, after clicking an exit button. (So maybe with a global variable?)
I want to do it as simple as possible. I was wondering if there is anything similar to isServerOn or so.
What I have so far is just this code below and if there would be a chance to add just one or few lines then it would be the best. Thank you all so much!!

```
import sys
    def quit()
       sys.exit()
```

Comment: Really depends if you have locked any resources that would need to be released, or if you have forked any subprocesses that needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: "every service in the app" it sounds like you should provide more detail about the runtime structure of your "app" and its environment.

Answer (score 0):

To stop a python script use the keyboard: `Ctrl + C`

To stop it using code you can use these sections (Python 3) :

```
raise SystemExit
```

you can also use:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

or:

```
exit()
```

or:

```
import os
os._exit(0)
```